# jQuery register events in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i register "on" events in loop:

```
evetns = [
    "click"
    "mouseover"
    ...
]
for(events...) {
    $(document).on(events[i], 'someTarget', function() {...});
}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to bind multiple types of events to all run the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't register events in a for loop is my answer.

The `on()` function delegates the events on the same object, so there is no need for this kind of trickery. What you can do is to use `events.join(' ')`.

This way the `$(document)` object gets all the events in a string separated by a single space resulting in:

```
$(document).on('click mouseover ...', function(){/**/});
```

Now the trick to optimize this, I'd say is use an eventHandler that maps specific functions to separate events.

```
$(document).on(events.join(' '), myEventHandler);

function myEventHandler(e){
    switch (e.type){
        case 'click': return myClickFn(e);
        case 'mouseover': return myOverFn(e);
        default: return false;
    }
}
```

This way all functionality can be kept separate in the browser's memory.

Imagine without the switch statement, you can achieve all events to fire the same function at the same time the event occurred. If that is what you need however, I suggest to use [throttle or debounce](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/) to handle this use-case.

Comment: Maybe `case 'click': return myClickFn(e);` (and no `break`)? I'd pass the whole `event` object to the individual handlers in case they want to stop propagation or whatever.

Comment: Yes maybe, does it add value to my message, let's say ... 'memory optimization' wise?

Comment: Well my point is that the return value from the event handler has meaning, so if you don't return the value from the individual handlers that changes the behaviour.

Comment: Yep, looks better. Was also looking [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-functions) based on what you said. Since it can be further optimized into a better polymorphic solution I believe. But I don't want to go this far in my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly this should do what you want

```
var events = ['click', 'mouseover'];

console.log($('.dog'))
function registerEvents() {
    events.forEach(function(value, index) {
        $(".dog").on(value, onEvent); // Replace ".dog" with your own selctor
    });
}

function onEvent(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
}

registerEvents();
```

If you want to repeat `registerEvents()` every minute you could do something like

```
setInterval(registerEvents, 60000) // Repeat every minute
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers, you can use `let` to make the index block-scoped:

```
for(let i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
    $(document).on(events[i], 'someTarget', function() {...});
```